# php use array_slice in nested array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have an array like this

```
$data = array( 
    '2021-08-31' => array( 'country_id' => array( '191' => array( '20098' ) ) ),
    '2021-08-18' => array( 'country_id' => array( '214' => array( '14876' ) ) ),
    '2021-07-12' => array( 'country_id' => array( '103' => array( '19709' ) ) ),
    '2021-07-07' => array( 'country_id' => array( '206' => array( '9568' ) ) ),
    '2021-06-28' => array( 'country_id' => array( '246' => array( '19561' ), '132' => array( '19277' ), '1' => array( '2816' ), '83' => array( '19530' ), '21' => array('3340'), '202' => array( '14136' ), '103' => array( '17006' ) ) ),
    '2021-06-25' => array( 'country_id' => array( '99' => array( '14561' ), '102' => array( '26789' ), '21' => array( '7690' ), '21' => array( '242325' ), '11' => array('436432'), '999' => array( '43734' ), '768' => array( '34437' ) ) ),
```

);

Here I want to apply `array_slice` only for `country_id` element.
So lets say if I want to show first 6 elements of country id then it should something like this

```
$data = array( 
    '2021-08-31' => array( 'country_id' => array( '191' => array( '20098' ) ) ),
    '2021-08-18' => array( 'country_id' => array( '214' => array( '14876' ) ) ),
    '2021-07-12' => array( 'country_id' => array( '103' => array( '19709' ) ) ),
    '2021-07-07' => array( 'country_id' => array( '206' => array( '9568' ) ) ),
    '2021-06-28' => array( 'country_id' => array( '246' => array( '19561' ), '132' => array( '19277' ) ) ),
);
```

If I want to show elements from 3 to 9 then it should show something like this

```
$data = array( 
    '2021-07-12' => array( 'country_id' => array( '103' => array( '19709' ) ) ),
    '2021-07-07' => array( 'country_id' => array( '206' => array( '9568' ) ) ),
    '2021-06-28' => array( 'country_id' => array( '246' => array( '19561' ), '132' => array( '19277' ), '1' => array( '2816' ), '83' => array( '19530' ), '21' => array('3340') ) ),
);
```

So can someone tell me how to achieve this without changing key value pair of above array.
Any help and suggestions would be really appreciable.

Comment: It could be done with array_map method https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php. This would loop through the outer array and then the callback would use slice based on given parameters and return the array with specific country_id nodes.

Comment: or array_walk may be more simple since it sounds like you may want to pass params to the callback method to change which country_ids are returned. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: @SmileIT can you share some sample code for the above issue so that it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Following logic might help you on your way. Just set the slice you'd like to extract with `$start` and `$end` and the result is stored in array `$store`:

```
// set your slice with start and end
$start = 3;
$end = 9;

$count = 0;
$store = []; // the result store
foreach($data as $date => $record) {
    foreach($record['country_id'] as $k => $countryIds) {
        foreach($countryIds as $id) {
            $count++;
            if($count >= $start && $count <= $end) $store[$date]['country_id'][$k] = $countryIds;
        }
    }
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/fgorg)